# Implementing in app purchase and its restoration in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, in-app-purchase, restore

I have implemented in app purchase in one of my application using MKStoreManager.Now got a new guideline from apple that if you are doing in app purchase,you  have to give the user,the option for restoring the already purchased application.So i have done like this.On the 'restore' button click,this method is called.

```
- (void) checkPurchasedItems
{
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; 
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

and from here,this method is fired

```
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
    {
     NSMutableArray* purchasableObjects  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
        {
            NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
            [purchasableObjects addObject:productID];
        }

    }
```

But now i have a doubt that how can i check this restoration is working or not.Can anyone guide me.thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check by creating Test user in itunesConnect. Buy you application using test user and delete your application and check restoration is working or not

Comment: @Sumanth i have created a sandbox account  for this.Can i know the code i have used is correct or not for the restoration?

Comment: And on testing with the sandbox account that i created, i am getting this warning "This account doesn't have permission to make in app purchases. You can change account permissions in iTunes Connect."

Comment: Yes that was the correct code for restoring the purchase.
For second can you show me the screen shot of the warning

Comment: @Sumanth i have corrected that by changing the location to US.And now it starts downloading.But is not get downloaded.And when i am trying again to download,i am getting the warning as in the scree shot.And even after clicking ok,it is not downloaded.The screen shot is attached.

Comment: YEs it will come because you have previously buy your application before, so it was stating you have already purchased. Here you are not restoring previous transaction
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; 
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
You need to call these two line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13334/discussion-between-sumanth-and-alpz)

Comment: I got the same issue of "This account doesn't have permission to make in app purchases. You can change account permissions in iTunes Connect."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you implement the Restoration

```
- (void)loadStore
{
// restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

// get the product description (defined in early sections)
[self requestProUpgradeProductData];
}

- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId];
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]     initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];

// we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}
```

After this it will call this method

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
NSArray *products = response.products;
proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products objectAtIndex:0] retain] : nil;
if (proUpgradeProduct)
{
NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(purchaseProUpgrade)]) {
        [self purchaseProUpgrade];
    }
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Error"] message:@"Cannot connect to Store.\n Please Enable the Buying in settings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
}

for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
{
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
[cancelButton setEnabled:YES];
[buyNowButton setEnabled:YES];
[restoreButton setEnabled:YES];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Error occured" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
}

// finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
[productsRequest release];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]         postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
[self recordTransaction:transaction];
[self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}
- (void)purchaseProUpgrade
{
[SVProgressHUD showInView:self.view status:[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Connecting Store"] networkIndicator:YES];
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment     paymentWithProductIdentifier:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId])
{
// save the transaction receipt to disk
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
}
```

Finally this method

```
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:        (BOOL)wasSuccessful
{
// remove the transaction from the payment queue.
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
if (wasSuccessful)
{
//Write your transaction complete statement required for your project
}
```